# format specifier error

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting

I am getting the error message: `expected ':'` presumably because of the phrase `initWithTitle:@"You downloaded %i boards", iboard` below. Can you help me fix it?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You downloaded %i boards", iboard message:@"Press Ok to continue" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
```

Comment: Why are you making assumptions about what methods do and do not do? Who told you that you can use variadic formatting with *any* method expecting an `NSString`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
initWithTitle:@"You downloaded %i boards", iboard
```

with

```
initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You downloaded %i boards", iboard]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done a mess with your code.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You downloaded %i boards", iboard message:@"Press Ok to continue" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

It should be :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You downloaded %i boards", iboard]
                                                message:@"Press Ok to continue" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: Nah, it shouldn't. Check the other answer.

Comment: @H2CO3: I was typing the answer, now i am done. If still any error plzzzz suggest.